# "А ля герр ком а ля герр" и прочие иноязычные поговорки

Tags: иностранные-слова

Допустимо ли в тексте иноязычные поговорки писать русскими буквами или все-таки надо всегда писать на языке оригинала?

Answer (score 2):

Их надо писать на языке оригинала, иначе получается такая ерунда, как транслит.

Comment: Не всегда ж знаешь, как оно пишется, например, на том же французском!

Comment: Более серьезно, что не всегда возможно идентифицировать какой же язык подразумевал автор. Ну, и читатель не всегда знает как читается то или иное слово. Ну, например, слово rot. Прозношение может быть от "рат" до "рот". Или взять немецкий. Мне бы никогда не пришло в голову, что Sonne произносится как "зоне", а zeit - цайт. Поэтому лучше всего сделать какие-либо сноски, как у великих русских авторов, когда они вводили в текст иностранный язык.

Answer (score 1):

Транслит совсем не ерунда, а мощное средство языка. В художественной литературе вполне приемлемо писать иноязычные фразы русскими буквами в кавычках. В переводах для нотариального заверения на русский язык латиница практически вообще не приемлема, поэтому иного выхода нет, как транслитерировать что бы то ни было. То есть надо смотреть по стилю, насколько он позволят сохранять латиницу и есть ли в этом смысл. В принципе иноязычные фразы желательно адаптировать для широкой аудитории (переводить или транслитерировать). 
Итого, надо учитывать стиль и предназначение текста, ориентироваться на его восприятие адресатом. А в принципе писать иноязычные фразы русскими буквами в кавычках, конечно же, допустимо.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего писать русский эквивалент.
Если не получается - французский (ангийский, немецкий, итальянcкий) оригинал.
Но как, простите, быть, например, с японским?
Так что в качестве наихудшего, но все-таки возможного, я вариант с русской транслитерацией допускаю.

Comment: >Но как, простите, быть, например, с японским?
иероглифами! Или романдзи.

Answer (score 0):

По Розенталю (а пока мы вроде бы считаем его пособия экспертными, нет?), "написания иностранных слов (...остающихся "чужеродным телом" в составе русского языка) передаются с возможным приближением к их образованию и произношению в языке-источнике. Приведем некоторые примеры: *а-капелла... "Гран-при"... жен-премьер... о'кэй... файвоклок...*"

Comment: Это всё одиночные слова, а автор вопроса спрашивает про цельные предложения (поговорки).

Comment: Не вижу принципиальной разницы. Поговорку редко можно назвать совершенно самостоятельным предложением.
Обширные пассажи типа того, с которого начинается роман Толстого, - другое дело, но сейчас подобное вряд ли актуально.

Comment: Разница в другом. Это слова, вошедшие или входящие в русский язык. А мы говорим о цельном выражении, которое само по себе никогда в язык не войдет, иначе как в своём идиоматическом значении. К тому же у таких идиом почти всегда есть русский эквивалент.

Answer (score 0):

Сторонники написания иностранных поговорок на языке-оригинале!!! Напишите-ка на языке оригинала арабские, китайские поговорки и поговорки ещё тысяч языков, которые пишутся не на латинице и кириллице. Вы уже не замечаете, что говоря ВСЕ языки, во ВСЕХ языках, вы пребываете только в английском, немного французском, чуть-чуть латинском. Даже по-гречески вы как будете писать? Даже клавиатуру где будете заказывать? Но даже, если буквы из интернета надергаете - кто поймет всю прелесть вашей поговорки??? Вернитесь на землю! Вернитесь уже к русскому языку. В языке ВСЕ должно писаться на алфавите этого языка. Иначе это не язык, а помойка.